# NodeJs run for each loop parallel

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, ecmascript-6

i'm currently using this for each loop to fetch data from my mysql database:

```
//...sql query returns result

var obj = {};
Object.assign(obj, result);

async.forEach(obj, function (item, callback){
                switch(item.type){
                    case 11:
                        //for example counting likes
                        db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS likes FROM tbl_post_likes WHERE BINARY post_id = ?", [item.post_id], function(err, res){
                            if(err) throw err;

                            item.likes = res[0].likes;
                            callback();

                        });
                        break;
                    case 12:

                        /*I haven't completed the other types yet.
                          But they are having similar queries
                          because there are different kind of posts.
                          I want to to run these queries parallel */

                        callback();
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        callback();
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        callback();
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("wtf?: " + result[i]);
                        callback();
                        break;
                }

            }, function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                console.log(obj);
                res.end(JSON.stringify(obj));

            });
```

At the end i wan't to output the object "obj" as JSON with all the required informations.

Thank you very much for your help & sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Use async.eachSeries  instead of async.forEach

Following documentation explains in detail,

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

More examples here,

http://wirama.web.id/node-js-array-looping-with-async/

Comment: Please accept as an answer if that solves your problem, or if you still run into issues, share it here and see what is the issue further.

Comment: eachseries "The same as each but runs only a single async operation at a time.".  Isn't his goal to run in parallel not series?  Perhaps just a poorly worded question.

Comment: Problem is by default by runs parallel and want to run one by one.

Comment: second hyperlink says "That page can’t be found"